# AS3 BitmapData HitTest doesn't work

Tags: actionscript-3, collision-detection, hittest, bitmapdata

I'm working on a flash game where I'm using bitmapdata to determine collision detection with a platform and a ship. so the problem in my code is the function "CheckHitTest()". the ship must be Red when a collision detection!

here is the bitmapdata of the ship (inside ship class):

```
this.BData = new BitmapData(860,520, true, 0);
```

and the same for the level (inside level/platform class):

```
this.BData = new BitmapData(this.width,520, true, 0);
```

and this is the where my problem comes:

```
private function CheckHitTest():void 
{
    var Levelbdata = this.level.GetBData() as BitmapData;
    var Shipbdata = this.ship.GetBData() as BitmapData;
    var Alpha:uint = 255;

    if (Shipbdata.hitTest(new Point(this.ship.x, this.ship.y), Alpha, Levelbdata, new Point(this.level.x, this.level.y), Alpha)){
        this.ship.MakeItRed(); //hitTest = true !
    }else{
        this.ship.MakeItGreen(); //hitTest = false !
    }
```

the full source code here: [Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D1cba_sY0qPI4vXNwNUQ6CPATqZ-I8W-/view?usp=drive_web)

hope you guys help me ! because i have failed so far. thank you

Comment: Is this solved now? Either you still need an Answer or you should share your working solution for others with same issue. Thanks.

Comment: the problem still unsolved! and i give up on it